# Can I combine the computing power of two laptops for everyday use?

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop, teamviewer, cluster, screen-sharing

I have two laptops by different makers, both running Windows 10. Neither of them is comfortable enough for MS Office use or normal Web browsing. One has a better display, a quicker but smaller SSD, and an inferior Celeron CPU; the other has a poor display, a slower but bigger HDD, and a superior i3 CPU. The RAM is 4 gigabytes in both cases. Unfortunately, none of their extractable parts may be mixed together within either of them.

But can I combine their functions by software means?

The following ideas come to my mind:

- Set up an RDP connection so that the slower CPU / better display laptop be used as the terminal;
- Set up something like TeamViewer;
- Set up a cluster to share the RAM and the CPU;
- Use the laptop with the better display as a monitor for the other laptop;
- Install linux on both or one of them, and set up a cluster or remote desktop environment there.

What sounds more reasonable? Is there a better solution?

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**In short, no**: you cannot combine the two laptops

You would face multiple issues such as lack of space, lack of compability of hardware components.

Instead:

I would go for the laptop with the good display (which is important for day-to-day use), the SSD over a HDD which typically has higher access and write speed and upgrade/modify that one to **furfill the requirements you describe**.

While the Intel Celeron family is indeed market-entry level, it could be overclocked to provide you with a better performance such as detailled here: [intel celeron overclocking](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-celeron-overclocking-guide,218.html).

As for running the software, I would go for running Linux over Windows, especially when trying to maintain or revive legacy hardware for standard day-to-day use computers. Some distro's I could recommand are the light-weight `xubuntu` family or `Manjaro`, a more user-friendly distro based on the rolling-release schedule of Arch Linux. You can install ONLYOFFICE desktop editors software on linux using Snap, which provide you with a minimal, office like version of Word, Excel and Powerpoint including support for saving and opening the relevant extensions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/813818)

Comment: Hey @Chenmunka, thanks for your feedback; I've updated my answer now, such that it should be more clear now why I would go for upgrading the one laptop instead of building some kind of Frankstein-equivalent two laptop device

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. I did not ask about hardware. The question was about software solutions. My Celeron laptop may not be upgraded because its RAM is soldered to the motherboard, and the CPU has no fan, hence may not be overclocked without overheating. I have used linux for a few years but running MS Office is not always possible there. That is why I asked for client-server type solutions. I agree that a good display is important,  so I am yhinking about using the Cel laptop as a client.